# Material UI Button not displayed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Follow is my content of `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App.js1`

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

function App() {
  return  <Button variant="contained">Button</Button>
}

export default App;
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And you can see in the following picture, nothing is displayed (supposedly to display a button):
[image]

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed the MUI library, follow the [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) and install this:

`npm install @mui/material`

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) to install Material UI.

First, try:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Then, import `@font`

```
npm install @fontsource/roboto
```

Add to `index.js`

```
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';
```

And if you want to using icon of Material UI, try:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Hope that help